# Webpack cannot resolve custom JS file

Tags: javascript, webpack, knockout.js

We are trying to migrate from grunt to webpack.

In our project, we use a JS file called boiler to define the frequently accessed core classes.

```
__boiler__.js

define(function (require) {
  return {
    Helpers: require('helpers/_helpers_'),
    Enums: require('enums/_enums_'),
    Context: require('context'),
    ...
  };
});
```

And Web Pack Config

```
webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.scss'],
    alias: {
      app: path.resolve(__dirname, './dev_files/app'),
      Boiler: path.resolve(__dirname, './dev_files/app/core/_boiler_')
    }
  },
  entry: './dev_files/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Then when I tried to do webpack build, it gave me some errors like:

```
ERROR in ./dev_files/app/core/_boiler_.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'context' in 'C:\Myproject\dev_files\app\core'
resolve 'context' in 'C:\Myproject\dev_files\app\core'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Myproject\package.json (relative path: ./dev_files/app/core)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
    ....
```

I'm a noob when in JavaScript and WebPack in general. Could someone give me an idea what am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using require for your module loading.

try to export your definition so that it can be found/included by webpack

```
module.export = (function (require) {
  return {
    Helpers: require('helpers/_helpers_'),
    Enums: require('enums/_enums_'),
    Context: require('context'),
    // ...
  };
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is. Thanks a lot!